# Отображение шрифта. Rendered fonts

Tags: html, css

Не понимаю как так происходит: я задаю шрифт, например 'Roboto', открываю браузер, навожу на элемент и вижу что он как и нужно со шрифтом 'Roboto'. Но когда открываю devtools, то вижу в отрендеренных шрифтах Arial Black, а на странице всё верно...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в итоге была проблема с путями(

Answer (score 1):

В случае если вы для импорта шрифта Roboto используете Google Fonts, переместите инструкцию `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap');` к началу вашей таблицы стилей, так, чтоб она была самой первой строкой в вашем коде

Я сталкивался с этой проблемой, и такое решение всегда срабатывало. После того, как строка будет перемещена, убедитесь в консоли разработчика, что шрифты грузятся вашим браузером на вкладке Network

Comment: я делаю приложение на реакте и подключаю шрифты через font.css, есть папка public, где и лежат шрифты, подключаются они в ndex.html, который тоже лежит в public. Для просмотра компонентов используется storybook и там в стилях каждого компонента указываются соответствующие шрифты, при просмотре страницы они отображаются правильно в разметке. Но rendered fonts всё равно не верные, уже по разному пробовал, не нашёл решение.